# Countifs to return value from group of columns

Tags: excel, countif

How to fix this error

```
=COUNTIFS(b:b,a1,c:d,">1")
```

but works for a single column

```
=COUNTIFS(b:b,a1,c:c,">1")
```

Comment: do you want the count where `B:B = A1 AND C:C > 1 AND D:D >1` or `B:B = A1 AND (C:C > 1 OR D:D >1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft documents specifically provides that Each additional range must have the same number of rows and columns as the criteria_range1 argument. The ranges do not have to be adjacent to each other. Try to change your formula like this:
=COUNTIFS(B:B,A1,C:C,">1",D:D,">1")
This formula allows 127 pairs in office 2010, 2013, 2016, 2019 and office 365.